can't get *only* desired output from awk command
I'm trying to parse a file using awk to return an array of 4 arguments in an applescript, but am not getting the desired result.
Here's the awk command:
awk -F '%' '{if ($1=="Actions") print ($2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5)}' "/Users/<my_username>/Desktop/windowInfo.txt"
And here's the content of the file:
Actions%3773%22%1347%699
Transport%3431%1199%665%97
Undo History%3431%1276%665%164

The best I've been able to do is getting the 4 arguments I want separated by commas, but then it always additionally returns the first argument from the next line after a newline. Even when I use awk -F '%|\n' to include the newline as a separator, it's still returning the same result with the first argument of the following line on a newline.
example of the output I'm getting:
3773,22,1347,699
Transport

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Please help!
For context, I am trying to call this from an applescript using the following syntax to return window position and size data from a text file based on window name matching:
repeat with winName in winNames
    set shellCommand to "awk -F '%' '{if ($1==\"" & winName & "\") print $2,$3,$4,$5}' " & filePath
    set {winX, winY, winW, WinH} to (do shell script shellCommand)
    if (winX is not "") and (winY is not "") and (winW is not "") and (WinH is not "") then
        tell application process "Finder"
            set theWindow to (every window whose name is winName)
            if (count of theWindow) > 0 then
                set position of theWindow to {winX, winY}
                set size of theWindow to {winW, winH}
            end if
        end tell
    end if
end repeat


The first awk command you show is not the same as the awk command in your applescript script. Why?

I have the strong suspicion that your file does not contain LF (\n) but only CR (\r). So it actually sees a single record with many fields of which you only print field 2 till 5 where the fifth field is something like 699\rtransport. you could consider to define -v RS="\r"

Isn't this a duplicate question? Save/Restore the Bounds of Every Open Window by Path/Name

Does this answer your question? AppleScript: Save/Restore the Bounds of Every Open Window by Path/Name

Don't let any variable, shell or otherwise, e.g. winName in the script at the bottom of your question, expand to become part of an awk script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script for how to pass the value of a variable to awk.

@Renaud Pacalet command is slightly different due to lack of sleep/human error, and because I simplified the command for the first example instead of showing the iterative context first.

@kvantour OMG you're probably right! I didn't even think to try adding \r. :facepalm:

@Mockman no, this is specific to an issue regarding awk, showing context of a similar Applescript use, but for a different app than Finder (REAPER). Also, for the question you linked I was the OP. :)

@Ed Morton thanks for the tip! I'll read up on it.

On Unix/Linux machines, the nominal files end lines with \n. Where on MacOS they are ending with \r. On windows machines, they use \r\n. Since awk has a default record separator of \n it only finds a single record, which is the full file.
To solve your issue, you have to add:
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r";FS="%"; OFS=","}($1=="Actions"){print $2,$3,$4,$5}' /path/to/file


It's been a long time since MacOS used this convention for text files. If this works, great; but it seems like basically a no repro.

Line endings on a mac are actually \n by default as well, and within the shell, that should be what the result is. However, when do shell script was implemented, the situation was murkier, and so it modifies what the script returns. Apple ended up adding an option, altering line endings which lets you decide how you want do shell script to return the result. To get \n, append without altering line endings to the command. Personally, I wish they'd done the reverse but…

@tripleee in my case, I've been using the same old Mac and OS for a "long time" (MBP Retina, macOS Sierra, since 2017), so old conventions still apply for me.

@Mockman Good stuff to know. Thanks again!
